# Android Studio - java.lang.invoke cannot resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, import, java-8, method-invocation

I try to use MethodHandlers on Android Stduion. My jdk path is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home`

But I cannot import `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles`. This class is available since 1.7

How can I resolve it?

Comment: it is also availabe in Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html Nobody can tell you what is the problem in your case without providing some more information.

Comment: Do you have a *minSDKVersion* of at least *26*? It's not available for any API level below that.